# Specific find-all-points-on-surface problem

Tags: multivariable-calculus

### problem

Find all points on the surface
$$
f(x,y,z) = x^2 + 2y^2 + 3z^2 + 2xy + 2yz = 1
$$
where the tangent plane is parallel to the plane
$$
x - y + 2z = 0 
$$

### NOTE THIS EDIT

I had made a typo ($3yz$ instead of $2yz$) in the original equation. I will try solving it again now and then see what I will do about this question since the rest from here might be irrelevant (except for the answer).

### my try at solving it

The normal vector $n_1$ of the plane is $(1,-1,2)$ and I compute the gradient of the surface to the following (square brackets for emphasizing components)
$$
\nabla f(a,b,c) = ([2(a+b)], [2a+4b+3c], [3b+6c])
$$
which is a normal vector $n_2$ of the point $(a,b,c)$ on the given surface.

Then, like all other *find-all-points-questions* I try to compute the cross product $n_2 \times n_1$ since it should equal to the zero-vector if they are parallel. From this, however, I get the set of equations
$$
\begin{cases}
4a + 11b + 12c = 0\\
4a + b - 6c = 0\\
3b + 6c = 0
\end{cases}
$$
which I see doesn't lead to anything but $a=b=c=0$ since there are no constants involved (incorrect if I'm not missing something here).

### my other try

I also tried to set the $n_2$ components equal to the $n_1$ components, since they should point in the same direction, and then I think I can scale the expression by inserting the points in the original function $f$ and scale them to equal $1$. So I set up the following system of equations
$$
\begin{cases}
2a + 2b = 1\\
2a + 4b + 3c = -1\\
3b + 6c = 2
\end{cases}
$$
and solve it using Gauss-Jordan giving me
$$
\begin{cases}
a=13/2\\
b=-6\\
c=10/3
\end{cases}
$$
and I get the tedious expression
$$
13^2/4 + 72 + 100/3 + 13(-6) - 6\cdot 10 = 115/12
$$
which also is incorrect, since the answer is supposed to be
$$
\pm \left( \frac{5}{\sqrt{13}}, \frac{-4}{\sqrt{13}} ,\frac{2}{\sqrt{13}} \right)
$$
which I can't get from scaling the points $a,b,c$ with the factor $115/12$. I have gone through this exercise several times, I have compared with similar exercises and I don't know what to do. Can anyone see what I'm missing or point at where I'm doing wrong? Is my approach even correct for this specific question?

Comment: Your "other try" makes sense and II can't get that either. I put $\nabla f = \lambda n$ where n is the plane normal vector and get $\lambda^2 = \frac{12}{115}$ as you do.

Comment: It’s no surprise that you can’t come up with the supposedly correct answer—it doesn’t even lie on the surface. Double-check the original problem and solution key. They clearly don’t match.

Comment: *sigh*... it's supposed to be $2yz$ and not $3yz$ in the original equation. I thought I had double-checked that several times already. What should I do with the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

should be
$$
\begin{cases}
2a + 2b = \lambda\\
2a + 4b + 3c = -\lambda\\
3b + 6c = 2 \lambda
\end{cases}
$$
$$
\begin{cases}
a=13 \lambda/2\\
b=-6 \lambda\\
c=10 \lambda/3
\end{cases}
$$
or back to
$$
\begin{cases}
x=13 \lambda/2\\
y=-6 \lambda\\
z=10 \lambda/3
\end{cases}
$$
with
$$x^2 + 2y^2 + 3z^2 + 2xy + 3yz = 1$$
Fewer errors if we define
$$ \lambda = 6t $$ and
$$
\begin{cases}
x=39t\\
y=-36 t\\
z=20t
\end{cases}
$$
$$x^2 + 2y^2 + 3z^2 + 2xy + 3yz = 345 t^2$$
and
$$ t = \pm \frac{1}{ \sqrt {345} } $$

Comment: Are you substituting for $6t$ to get rid of the fractions, or is there another specific reason?

Comment: @BCI4evry1 it seems it should actually have been $2yz \; \; ? \; $

Comment: Yes, I didn't find that typo before asking the question unfortunately... What should I do about the question? Also, still curious, is $6t$ only for getting rid of the fractions?

Comment: @BCI4evry1 yes, just the fractions. Correct the original question but do not delete it.

Answer (score 0):

Your first approach was fine, but you made an error in the computation of $n_1\times n_2$. The correct system of equations has nontrivial solutions which then can be analyzed further.